# How do I turn this .txt into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, whatsapp

I am trying to do a Whatsapp analysis in Python and I want to convert this into a dataframe with columns for date, hour, person, and message.

```
 '[8/23/17, 1:45:10 AM] Guillermina: Guten Morgen',
 '[8/23/17, 1:47:05 AM] Kester Stieldorf: Good morning :) was in Düsseldorf one hour ago ;)',
 '[8/23/17, 1:47:16 AM] Guillermina: Hahahaha',
 '[8/23/17, 1:47:19 AM] Guillermina: What?',
 '[8/23/17, 1:47:36 AM] Kester Stieldorf: Yeah had to pick something up',
```

The text is longer than that. I have already tried with:

```
pieces = [x.strip('\n') for x in file_read.split('\n')]
beg_pattern = r'\d+/\d+/\d+,\s+\d+:\d+\s+\w+\.\w+\.'
pattern = r'\d+/(\d+/\d+),\s+\d+:\d+\s+\w+\.\w+\.\s+-\s+(\w+|\w+\s+\w+|\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+|\w+\s+\w+\.\s+\w+|\w+\s+\w+-\w+|\w+\'\w+\s+\w+|\+\d+\s+\(\W+\d+\)\s+\d+-\d+\W+|\W+\+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\W+|\W+\+\d+\s+\d+\w+\W+):(.*)'

reg = re.compile(beg_pattern)
regex = re.compile(pattern)

remove_blanks = [x for x in pieces if reg.match(x)]
blanks = [x for x in pieces if not reg.match(x)]

grouped_data = []
for x in remove_blanks:
    grouped_data.extend(regex.findall(x))

grouped_data_list = [list(x) for x in grouped_data]
```

But it doens't look to be working. I am pretty sure there is an issue with re.compile(), because when I print reg and regex, they return empty arrays. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are the quotation marks and end-of-line commas part of the original text file?

Comment: Yes, the quotation marks and end-of-line commas are part of the original text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to parse your file:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    pieces = [i.strip() for i in f.read().splitlines()]
```

Then using `re.findall`:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]\s*([^:]+):\s*(.*)', '\n'.join(pieces)),
    columns=['Time', 'Name', 'Text']
)
```

```
                  Time              Name  \
0  8/23/17, 1:45:10 AM       Guillermina
1  8/23/17, 1:47:05 AM  Kester Stieldorf
2  8/23/17, 1:47:16 AM       Guillermina
3  8/23/17, 1:47:19 AM       Guillermina
4  8/23/17, 1:47:36 AM  Kester Stieldorf

                                                Text
0                                       Guten Morgen
1  Good morning :) was in Düsseldorf one hour ago ;)
2                                           Hahahaha
3                                              What?
4                      Yeah had to pick something up
```

Comment: MY BAD! The quotation marks are NOT part of the text.

Comment: Then remove the quotation marks and comma from the end of the regular expression. I updated the answer